# How to calculate similarity between two clusters?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, clustering

I have generated clusters for two different datasets (d1 and d2) with Hierarchical Clustering algorithm and I would like to calculate the similarity between the clusters generated for d1 and d2. 
Example: Compare d1_1 to d2_1, where "_x" is the cluster number

Is important to note that each cluster can have different number of objects, but all clusters have the same attributes types:

```
**Atribute name**    **data type** 
Attr1         -         nominal 
Attr2         -         numerical
Attr3         -         nominal
Attr4         -         nominal 
Attr5         -         numerical
```

Example:

**Cluster 1 from d1:**

- Car, 12, Diesel, Black, 24
- Car, 13, Diesel, Blue, 2200
- Truck, 12, Diesel, Black, 24
- Car, 12, Diesel, Black, 82

**Cluster 1 from d2:**

- Car, 12, Gasoline, Black, 24
- Truck, 12, Diesel, Black, 24
- Car, 12, Diesel, Black, 82

---

If possible, I would like to have a value of similarity (between 2 clusters) between 0 and 1 or a percentage of similarity.

I assume that two clusters are similar if they have close numbers (if numeric type) and equal values (in nominal type)

Comment: You could use the mean (or median) cosine similarity.

Comment: @JairTaylor Could you give me an example how to use that in my problem? tks

Comment: @JairTaylor I updated my question to make more clear

Answer (score 1):

Define a distance function between data points and this becomes easier.
Let $F_x(i)$ be the $i$th numerical feature and $D_x(i)$ be the $i$th nominal feature (as a one-hot vector) of data point $x$.
Then the distance between data points $x$ and $y$ can be, for instance, 
$$ \delta(x,y) = \sum_i \gamma_i | F_x(i) - F_y(i) |^p + \eta\sum_j || D_x(j) - D_y(j) ||_2^2  $$
where we can choose $p,\gamma_i,\eta$ based on the data itself. 
For instance, we can choose $p=1$, $\eta=1/|D|$ as one over the number of nominal features, and $$ \gamma_i = \frac{1}{|F|\,|X|}\sum_{x\in X} F_x(i)  $$
as the weight for numerical feature $i$,
for the dataset $X$, so that the relative contribution of each term is similar in magnitude.

Then, given two clusters $C_1$ and $C_2$, there are many ways to compute normalized similarity. 
One is just
$$
S(C_1,C_2) = \frac{1}{1+\Delta(C_1,C_2)},\;\;\text{where}\;\; \Delta(C_1,C_2) = \frac{1}{|C_1|\,|C_2|} \sum_{x\in C_1} \sum_{y\in C_2} \delta(x,y)
$$
so that we get a similarity of $1$ when the clusters are identical and something close to $0$ when they are very different. Another, for instance, is $S_e(C_1,C_2)=\exp(-\Delta(C_1,C_2))$.

---

Alternatively, we could replace each $D_x(\ell)$ with a one-hot vector, and "unfold" each data point into a vector of numbers $\vec{x}$. Then we could compute a similarity via
$$
\tau_c(\vec{x},\vec{y}) = \frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}}{||\vec{x}||_2\,||\vec{y}||_2}
$$
which measures the angle between the unitized vectors in the data space.
This is the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), so $\tau_c\in[-1,1]$.
(Note that no attempt is made to account for the magnitude similarities across dimensions.)
Then we can measure overall similarity via
$$
S_c(C_1,C_2) = \frac{1}{|C_1|\,|C_2|} \sum_{x\in C_1} \sum_{y\in C_2}
\frac{\tau_c(\vec{x},\vec{y}) + 1}{2}
$$
which is $0$ for very different clusters and $1$ for very close ones.